# LSTM architecture for multivariate time series

Tags: keras, lstm, rnn

For a multivariate time series analysis, which of the following LSTM architectures would work better and why?

1) Having two independent LSTM layers (one for the time series variable and one for the features) and later concatenating these independent layers using Keras functional api.

2) Having both the time series variable and the features in one multidimensional array which is used in LSTM.

Comment: How do you distinguish between *variables* and *features*? Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: An example: the time series variable is the stock price (the thing you're trying to predict) and the features are some economic variables.

Comment: @physics_2015 what you call "variable" I call "predicted variable" or "label". Maybe if you post code your question will be clearer.